# Extract String from another in Javascript

Tags: javascript, split

Im facing a problem whit split in javascript , i want to extract a part in a string .
suppose x = CL_D_VX_USA-sys
i want to get just (CL_D_VX) in another variable Z for example.

Comment: Can you provide code for what you have already tried?

Comment: You would need to be able to articulate some rule about how the string it to be extracted (e.g. the first 7 characters, which could be done with `substr`, or pattern AA_A_AA where A is a char A-Z, which could be done with `RegExp`, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
x.substr(start_index, end_index)
```

To extract a string based on indices.

Consider writing a for-loop for more complex criteria.

```js
let x = 'CL_D_VX_USA-sys';
let z = x.substr(0, 7);

// Outputs CL_D_VX
console.log(z);
```